# What is the cost of upload/download to/from S3 or Glacier Deep Archive by using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I would like to know about the cost when we upload/download to/from S3 or Glacier. I want to make a Python script with boto3 library that downloads file from S3 and then groups chunks of files and zip them and send them to Glacier. Now, I would like to know is there a cost with those operations and would that way be cheaper than the standard way of sending files from S3 to Glacier. I tried to find the price, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest would be to use ec2 instance in the same region as your S3 and glacier region. This is [because](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

> Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) **within the same AWS Region are free**. You also pay a fee for any data transferred using Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration.